# No duplicate entries when uploading contact list in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I have an excel file that I upload to append my contact list in SugarCRM.  I would like for if a name the excel file is already present in the database, this particular entry is not appended.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Sugar import interface will also allow you to do duplicate checking as a part of the import process. See this page in the application guide:

http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarCommunityEdition/6.2/-docs-Application_Guides-Sugar_Community_Edition_Application_Guide_6.2.0GA-Import.html#1132356

Answer (score -1):

i think the easiest way for this is to:

1) export your current contact list to CSV

2) add it as a new in sheet in your current excel file

3) cross-reference which rows have are present between both (use 'vlookup' or 'match' on whatever criteria you use to determine duplicates)

4) filter the results so non-duplicates are shown, and save that as the a new CSV file

5) import the new csv-file via sugarcrm UI

hope this helps

Comment: Sugar allows for duplicate checking during importing in the "advanced" section. Check for duplicates using email address and you should be pretty safe.